# How to abort vimdiff in between viewing files?

Tags: svn, vim, diff

In my `.subversion/config` file, I have set `diff-cmd` as a script which invokes `vimdiff` to view the changes.

Following is my problem:
I am viewing diff between two svn URLS, which have 10 files modified. The `svn diff url1 url2` command would open the diff of first file. Issuing :qa in vim would show the diff of second file. Now, is there a way to quit vim altogether, aborting further viewing of diffs (other than running :qa for remaining 8 times)?

Update:
Following is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# use vimdiff to view diffs
DIFF="/usr/bin/vimdiff -o"


NUM=$#  # number of arguments
LEFT=${6} # old file
RIGHT=${7} # new file
L_TITLE=${3} # actual name and revision of old file
R_TITLE=${5} # actual name and revision of new file
ST="${L_TITLE}"

# get the file name
NAME=`echo $ST | tr -s ' ' '\n' | head -1` 
L_BRANCH=`echo $L_TITLE | tr -s ' ' '\n' | head -2 | tail -1`
R_BRANCH=`echo $R_TITLE | tr -s ' ' '\n' | head -2 | tail -1`

# get the old and new revision numbers
L_REV=`echo $L_TITLE | tr -s '(' '\n' | cut -d ')' -f1 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' '_' `
R_REV=`echo $R_TITLE | tr -s '(' '\n' | cut -d ')' -f1 | tail -1 | tr -s ' ' '_' `

L_REV=`echo "${L_BRANCH}__${L_REV}"`
R_REV=`echo "${R_BRANCH}__${R_REV}"`

# invoke vim
$DIFF $LEFT $RIGHT -c "setl stl=$NAME%20{'$L_REV'} | wincmd W | setl stl=$NAME%20{'$R_REV'}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Vim(diff) is invoked sequentially with pairs of files (by Subversion), the exit status of Vim would be a good way to indicate that the whole process is to be aborted. The `:cquit` command exits with an error code. If the surrounding executable already aborts the loop on error, you're done. Otherwise, that would have to be modified. As you seem to have an additional wrapper script around `vimdiff`, that one must not swallow Vim's exit status (and it looks like it doesn't).

Comment: I am not sequentially invoking pair of files. I have pasted my script in question. Vim is invoked once as: vimdiff -o <args>

Comment: Yeah, your script is just an additional wrapper. I meant the logic inside Subversion; hopefully, that's a script (or other easily modifiable program), so that you can adapt it.

Comment: Did you try whether `:cquit` affects the loop? And whoever downvoted this answer, a critique here in the comments would be much more helpful.

Comment: I tried :cquit, that does not help. :cquit and :qa behaves similarly.

Comment: Well then you either have to modify Subversion's script, or (new hacky idea) you check Vim's exit status inside your script, set a global flag (e.g. a marker file /tmp/vimdiffSkip) with a timestamp, and then in your wrapper skip the vimdiff invocation should that flag be set and have a recent timestamp.

Comment: I upvoted and wanted to note that this `:cquit` works for me when vimdiff is running through many files.

Comment: Very helpful for usage with `git mergetool -t vimdiff`, because `:qa!` will tell `git mergetool` the merge was successful

Answer (score 1):

- Subversion's `diff-cmd` treats any return value different than `0` or `1` as a fatal error.
- If you close vimdiff with `:cq`, it will exit with status code `1`.

You can use vimdiff's return value in your wrapper script to exit with a Subversion "fatal error", such as returning `2`.

If you add the following at the end of your script:

```bash
# if vimdiff returned 1, lets return a Subversion's fatal error code
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 2;
fi

exit 0
```

Doing that, if you close vimdiff with `:cq`, any remaining diffs will not be shown, and Subversion will show an error message such as:

```
svn: E200012: '/path/to/your/svn-diff-wrapper.sh' returned 2
```

Comment: `:cq` accepts a count or argument i think to tell it what exit code to use.

Answer (score 1):

A hack-job solution: `Ctrl-Z` to suspend vim, then `jobs` and `kill %N` where N is the job for the svn diff instance.

Not the cleanest solution, but the others didn't work for my specific svn/vimdiff setup, and when I accidentally diff 75 changed files I'd rather have a spare .swp file to clean up than enter :qa 75 times! I imagine this is a foolproof way to get out regardless of your diff script.